# Printing all possible combinations including duplicates, order matters too

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion

I am trying to combine two sets (vectors) into one big that has all elements of both including duplicates.

for example:

setA = "abc" and setB has "12345"
my output need to look like this:

```
{(a,1)(b,1)(c,1)}
{(a,1)(b,1)(c,2)}
{(a,1)(b,1)(c,3)}
{(a,1)(b,1)(c,4)}
{(a,1)(b,1)(c,5)}
{(a,1)(b,2)(c,1)}
{(a,1)(b,2)(c,2)}
{(a,1)(b,2)(c,3)}
{(a,1)(b,2)(c,4)}
{(a,1)(b,2)(c,5)}
{(a,1)(b,3)(c,1)}
{(a,1)(b,3)(c,2)}
.................    
{(a,5)(b,3)(c,5)}
{(a,5)(b,4)(c,1)}
{(a,5)(b,4)(c,2)}
{(a,5)(b,4)(c,3)}
{(a,5)(b,4)(c,4)}
{(a,5)(b,4)(c,5)}
{(a,5)(b,5)(c,1)}
{(a,5)(b,5)(c,2)} 
{(a,5)(b,5)(c,3)}
{(a,5)(b,5)(c,4)}
{(a,5)(b,5)(c,5)}
```

all 125 elements (5*5*5)

I tried to do this with for loop

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_setB.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < v_setB.size(); k++)
        {
            for (size_t n = 0; n < v_setB.size(); n++)
            {
                stringstream  temp;
                temp << "{(" << v_setA[0] << "," << v_setB[i] << ")(" << v_setA[1] << "," << v_setB[k] << ")(" << v_setA[2] << "," << v_setB[n] << ")}";
                v_SavedElem.push_back(temp.str());
            }
        }
    }
```

BUT if # of elements in first set grows then it will not work. Can some one help to create recursive function, please?

Comment: Are you comfortable with vector iterators? The solution works with or without them, but they're a good habit to get into.

Comment: When you say that with higher number of elements in the first set the solution "doesn't work" - what do you mean by that? And I have a very strong suspicion that the recursion is not an answer to your problem.

Comment: can you show me where to look, or maybe if possible show some code

Comment: higher number is referred to number of elements in 1st set (setA), if it has 4 elements "abcd" not 3 "abc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should take two sets (e.g. "abc" and "12345") as arguments, and produce the strings you describe.

So how about this: give it a third argument -- or better still make it the first -- that is a string to be used as a prefix for those strings. And another for the destination vector.

The function removes the first element from setA, and appends it to the prefix string. Then it iterates over the elements in setB, and either saves the results or calls the function again (with a shorter setA).

```
void foo(string pref, vector<char> v_setA, vector<char> v_setB, vector<string> &v_SavedElem)
{
  vector<char>::iterator itrA = v_setA.begin();
  pref += "(";
  pref += *itrA;
  pref+= ",";

  v_setA.erase(itrA);

  for(vector<char>::iterator itrB = v_setB.begin(); itrB!=v_setB.end(); ++itrB)
    {
      if(v_setA.empty())
      {
        stringstream  temp;
        temp << pref << *itrB << ")}" << endl;
        v_SavedElem.push_back(temp.str());
      }
      else
        foo(pref+*itrB+")", v_setA, v_setB, v_SavedElem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! thank you very much, your code is very easy to follow and understand.